# Unable to get the spinner in the center of the screen in android webview

Tags: java, android

This is my acitvy_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0">
        </ProgressBar>
    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity.class

```
package com.psudo.psudo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com/");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank you for visiting xyz!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

But the spinner is displayed on the left-hand top corner.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fg8Z.png

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riq8g.png)

the design is to get the spinner in the middle of the screen. Please help.

I have tried  android:gravity="center", android:foregroundGravity="center" but of now user.

if I change the

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to "match_parent", then the spinner is centered but is distorted and huge.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`FrameLayout`**. Add  `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"` this your **`ProgressBar`** section.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"/>
                

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @SrinivasPadmakar You can accept this answer if works

Answer (score 0):

You may not load a progressbar in the webview.

test it

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```